# TFS Workspace.Get method

Tags: .net, tfs

I am trying to do a workspace.get on a single file. However, when I call this method I am getting the entire directory and sub directories. What is the proper syntax to get the file only.

```
Workspace ws = _server.GetWorkspace(GetLocalPath(serverPath));
            ws.Get(new string[] { serverPath }, changesetSpec, RecursionType.Full, GetOptions.GetAll | GetOptions.Overwrite);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether `{ serverPath }` in your code below point to the specific file:

```
ws.Get(new string[] { serverPath }, changesetSpec, RecursionType.Full, GetOptions.GetAll | GetOptions.Overwrite);
```

Another way to get a specific file you can refer to [this article](https://paulselles.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/team-foundation-server-api-programmatically-downloading-files-from-source-control/):

```
string teamProjectCollectionUrl = "https://YourTfsUrl.com/tfs/YourTfsProjectCollection";

TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(teamProjectCollectionUrl));
VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

// Get the latest Item for local path "C:\projects\myfiles.cs"
Item item1 = versionControlServer.GetItem("C:\projects\myfiles.cs");

// Get ItemId = 12345 for changesetId = 54321
Item item2 = versionControlServer.GetItem(12345,54321);

// Get the latest Item for server path "$/ProjectName/myfile.cs"
Item item1 = versionControlServer.GetItem("$/ProjectName/myfile.cs", VersionSpec.Latest);
```

Comment: This was exactly it. I was not pointing at a valid file path. I also had to set recursionType.None as well